# Django webpage with JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, django

I am relatively new to Django and i am working on a webpage that uses JQuery. I am trying to have a header use the toggle feature to display more information, but when i load the page, the `<h3>` tag gets a style="display: none" added to it and the headers go away. I have added the static folder and all the necessary files to the folder and checked my settings.py to make sure everything is typed in correctly in the STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIR.

My jquery code in the webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.swarmdetails').hide();

            $('.span4 h3').toggle(
            function(){
                $(this).next('.swarmdetails').fadeIn(0);
                $(this).addClass('close');

            },//end of fadeIn
            function(){
                $(this).next('.swarmdetails').fadeOut(0);
                $(this).removeClass('close');
            }//end of fadeOut
        );//end of toggle

            $('.span4 li').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).popover('show');
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $(this).popover('hide');
            });

            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });

</script>
```

HTML that I am trying to toggle:

```
<div class="span9">
     <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span4">
             <h3 style="cursor: help">Resource Utilization</h3>
             <p class="swarmdetails">Here you can view every resource under your management.
                Filters include Project Name, Employee Name, etc </p>
         </div>

         <div class="span4">
             <h3 style="cursor: help">Direct Reports</h3>
             <p class="swarmdetails">Here you can view all managers
             and filter by name. You can use this option to quickly change an resource's
                        manager and also see who each manager has reporting to them.</p>

         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Can someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong so that i can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're using jQuery >= 1.8 for which the method signature `.toggle(handler, handler)` has been depracted (and than removed from version 1.9 on).

Could it be?

Comment: you know what...you are right. i took most of this code from the jsp version and didn't even think that the jquery versions were different. I will try that. Been looking at the screen took long. thanks.

Comment: That did it. I was using an older version of toggle. Its working now. thanks for the help.